# I want to take the return value from an object's function after 5 second in java

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

I'm making a basic card game that human user can play with computer or computer play with computer in java. I wanna take a selection as a random number from a selection function in the Computer Player class that extends my Player class. But I wanna take answer after 5 seconds from calling selection function. Also I must take a answer from selection function in Human Player class with mouse listener.

I create a waiter timer that start when calling my selection function.

```java
Timer waiter = new Timer(5000,this);
boolean is_waiting;

public int select_cart() {
        waiter.start();
        is_waiting = true;
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(getCartNumber()) + 1;
        int selection = random;
        while(is_waiting){
            System.out.println("Computer is selecting...");
        }
        return selection;
    }

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == waiter){
            is_waiting = false;
            waiter.stop();
        }
    }
```

I expect that select_cart function return a value after 5 second but this code print "Computer is selecting..." to console in endless loop.

Comment: select_cart() never stops running because it gets stuck . you need to develop a method that can check status without blocking, instead of waiting.

Comment: Stuck?Why it didn't enter to actionPerformed and didn't make is_waiting false? How do I prevent it from sending without waiting?

Comment: if select_cart() is "running" meaning having focus. it will not yield ever. it is stuck. you need to move the waiting logic out of that method create a timer that fires an event and when the event fires  you check if the value has updated then. this happens on a background thread and doesn't block.

Comment: You're likely blocking the Event Dispatching Thread.  Instead of "waiting" you should have the `actionPerformed` method just perform the action as required.  If `select_cart` is executing on a different thread, then I'd consider using a object monitor or a [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) or event a `CountDownLatch`.  You should ALWAYS avoid using "idle" loops (where ever possible), they are inefficient and cause more issues than they solve.

Comment: This may require you to change your approach slightly.  Instead of returning the value directly, you may need to use a callback to notify interested parties when then value has become avaliable

Comment: not swing but FX is the newer version and works similarly you can see a simple demo i made that animates things based on a timer https://github.com/mavriksc/FXTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## If `select_cart` is been called from the Event Dispatching Thread

Then you need to change your approach, as the `while-loop` is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, meaning that the `Timer`'s `actionPerformed` method will never be called.

In this case, a better approach would be to allow the `actionPerformed` method to actually trigger the result, but, you'll need to employ a observer pattern to make it work

Start by defining a callback `interface`, something like...

```
public interface CartSelection {
    public void cartSelection(int value);
}
```

Then you need to change the code to make use of this callback and move the core functionality to `actionPerformed`, for example...

```
Timer waiter = new Timer(5000,this);
CartSelection callback;

public void select_cart(CartSelection callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    waiter.start();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == waiter){
        waiter.stop();
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(getCartNumber()) + 1;
        int selection = random;
        callback(selection)
    }
}
```

Then you could call `select_cart` something like...

```
select_cart(new CartSelection() {
    @Override
    public void cartSelection(int value) {
        // Carry on...
    }
});
```

as an example.

If the cart is been filled by some other process, then you might consider using different approaches, such as using [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) objects to "wait" till the filling process completed.

Equally, you could use a `SwingWorker` to fill the cart and when it's completed, `publish` the results to be consumed via some other mechanism.

## If `select_cart` is been called from another thread

Now, if you're calling `select_cart` from a different thread (other then the EDT), then you don't actually need the `Timer` at all and could just do ...

```
public int select_cart() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int random = r.nextInt(getCartNumber()) + 1;
    int selection = random;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    return selection;
}
```

Comment: Thread.sleep(); was so helpful to me. I have fixed my get return with delay problem. But still I can't use mouseListener in my Human Player calass. I can't understand your first solution. How can I wait in Human Player class when call select_cart function that owerrided from parent Player class abstract function  until to mouse clicked to return value?

Comment: This is what I'm saying, you can't.  Not without blocking the EDT and then brining your whole App to a grinding stand still.  This is why you should make use of an observer pattern instead. To make it work, you're going to have to change the way you think